# Access row by column

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio

I want to access row by column. ex. I have 3 rows with 2 columns.

The value inside table

```
USERNAME PASSWORD
dipsy    pdipsy  
poo      ppoo
lala     plala
```

In this code it can print but I can't take full control the result to use next like compare, match. the reason I want to do this in array because array is more flexible than query compare or match. I am using C Connector API.

```
 #include "mysql.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    MYSQL * con = mysql_init(NULL);

    mysql_real_connect(con, "127.0.0.1", "root", "root", "StackOverFlow", 3306, NULL, 0);

    mysql_query(con, "SELECT username, password FROM maccount");


    MYSQL_RES * res = mysql_store_result(con);

    int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(res);

    MYSQL_ROW row;

    while((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
        { 
            // it print but it can't be control.
            cout << row[i] << endl;

           // i want like this. row[0] is username field, row[1] is password field
           cout << row[0] << row[1];
        }
    }


    mysql_free_result(res);
    mysql_close(con);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem if you write `cout << res[0] << "---" << res[1] << endl;` instead of the `for` loop?

Comment: "i want like this. row[0] is username field, row[1] is password field" What's the current behaviour? All references/examples I could find assert that row data is ordered by field index.